# Ubuntu keeps randomly freezing

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

My Ubuntu 11.04 installation keeps randomly freezing. I can't really find a pattern in when it happens.
First the cursor starts lagging behind for about 5 seconds, and then suddenly the whole screen freezes. Things like `CTRL+ALT+F1` also do not work at those times.
This is getting really annoying, and on the Ubuntu IRC no'one seems to be getting any further than I do.
This is my `dmesg`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/653077/
It froze again about 5 or 10 minutes ago.
I am using the `nvidia-173` drivers because Unity won't work using the `nvidia-current` ones.

### Edit

I seem to have solved most of these freezes myself by enlargin my swap partition. I thought I had a 1GiB one... turned out I made a mistake and had actually made it 1MiB xD I now resized it to 4**GiB**. But my computer still freezes regularly, and this is really pissing me off now... This is a more recent dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/664464/. It froze again a few minutes ago.