# Ubuntu 11.04 64bits Keeps Randomly Freezing

Tags: 11.04, gnome, freeze

This has been a real headache for me since the number of freezes has increase from twice a week to about 1 or twice a day. The system just halts and nothing can be done but hitting the restart button. At the beginning I thought it was related to Flash since I was getting random freezes when playing full screen flash videos online. I also thought it could be the wireless pci card. But the system has freezed using browsing around GNOME.

The truth is, the freezes are really random and strange. I checked this thread [Ubuntu keeps randomly freezing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54698/ubuntu-keeps-randomly-freezing) and try to ssh my computer using another one, but I could not ssh since it was really totally frozen. NumLock or CapsLock wasn't responding or blinking.

Since I could not ssh I, also ignored this article https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze

According to my wife, the system has also halted under Win7 Pro 64bit but with less frequency.

Here is my system configuration

- Intel Core i7 2600k
- ASRock Z68 Extreme3 gen3 Motherboard
- Crucial M4 128GB CT128M4SSD2 SSD
- WD Caviar Green WD10EADS 1TB SATA II
- G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR2
- OCZ ModXStream 600W Power Supply
- Rosewill RNX-N300X PCI Wireless Adapter
- No external Graphics Card

I remove the Wireless card and used Ethernet to see if the problem was the that, but I got a freeze after doing that.

I also ran memtest86 and everything was ok.

The only other thing I might suspect of is the SSD. I will try to clone the SSD to a HDD to see if that solve the problem.

At this point I am stuck with the freezes.

Do anyone have a clue of why this is happening and how can i solve this?

EDIT:

I clone my SSD to a HDD and my system hasn't freeze since then on Ubuntu or Win7, though it is significantly slower than before, as expected, specially in Windows.

What could possible be wrong with my SSD?::: Crucial M4 128GB CT128M4SSD2 SSD

Comment: A suggestion - perhaps related to overheating, or power supply problems.  At least, that's the only thing that's caused similar problems on my systems (where using a live cd/different OS hasn't made any difference).

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by accident. The problems was actually the SDD. For some reasons, the Drive doesn't perform well when no enough space is left at the end of the last partition for "Garbage Collection." I resized my last partition and left about 1GB left at the end of the drive. I have never got a freeze again.

Solution:

Leave at least 1GB free space at the end of the last partition in your Crucial M4 drive.

It works for me.